# For cycle to append excel sheets not workin

Tags: python, excel, pandas

im trying to append this sheets, but at the end only the first sheet is showing

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('MyFile.xlsx')


for sheetname in xls.sheet_names:
    sheetname = pd.read_excel('MyFile.xlsx', sheet_name = sheetname, header=[8,9])
    sheetname.drop(sheetname.tail(3).index,inplace=True)
    out_df = sheetname.append(sheetname)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below:

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('MyFile.xlsx')

for sheetname in xls.sheet_names:
    sheetname = pd.read_excel('MyFile.xlsx', sheet_name = sheetname, header=[8,9])
    sheetname.drop(sheetname.tail(3).index,inplace=True)
    out_df = out_df.append(sheetname)
    # -------^^^^^^
```

Correction marked